# Icon animation on the new NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to switch to the new NavigationView for my Drawer.

When i did (and its working fine), I lost the animation of the Menu icon to the Back icon when the Drawer is sliding.

How can i have that on the NavigationView?

Here is my code:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

mDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
if (mDrawer != null) {
    mDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us some more code that cointains the DrawertToggle

Comment: I don't have a DrawerToggle, i have removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot research, i solved it by simply adding the following:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Hope it helps.